# Unix: Find files with a number as the extension

Tags: unix, find

I'm trying to do a search on a directory to find just the files that have a number as the extension (i.e. file.12345, file2.23415, file3.85472).  Is there any way to do this in unix.  I have been trying to find a way using the find command and wildcards, such as:

```
find . -name \*.#####
```

where the # is a wildcard for a single number or even a string of numbers, however, there doesn't seem to be anything like this that I can find, so are there any other suggestions.  I am a fairly basic user of unix, but anything would help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `find . -print | grep -E '\.[0-9]+$'`.

Comment: +1 for this answer (over mine!), as it meets the OP's requirement of working on Unix (vs. Linux).

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly.  I do have just one more question.  How can I take the list this creates and output it to a file.  Similar to what `find . -name file1.* > list.txt` does?

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this?

```
find . -regex '.+\.[0-9]+'
```

Comment: `-regex` is a GNU extension, but +1.

Comment: As larsmans pointed out, I don't think the '-regex' extension is available in UNIX, or at least I could not get it to work.  Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to a non-Linux Unix box to test against.  You might find a better answer if asked at http://unix.stackexchange.com.